# Lenovo X230 running Kubuntu 22.04 - stops responding after one mouse click: ctrl/alt/del restart clears issue until next power up

Tags: kubuntu, startup, system

Snippet from "dmesg" seems to show sys waiting on bluetooth:

```
[    4.691846] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 3 fixed counters, 163840 ms ovfl timer
[    4.691851] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-16 Joules
[    4.691853] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-16 Joules
[    4.691855] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-16 Joules
[    4.696176] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    4.697301] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[    4.714099] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A
[    4.714105] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[    4.716682] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware Patch file not found, tried:
[    4.716687] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21e6.hcd'
[    4.716690] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: 'brcm/BCM-0a5c-21e6.hcd'
[    4.910651] input: HDA Intel PCH Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input14
[    4.921339] audit: type=1400 audit(1663853017.996:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=668 comm="apparmor_parser"
```

Comment: Formatting this info would be a good place to start. It is quite unreadable as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled "Intel AMT" setting the BIOS.
Problem is no longer occurring - Lenovo X230 boots and takes mouse clicks without locking up.